# android-java- how to send a message to specific client from server

Tags: java, android, client-server

I am a little confused about how to send a message to a specific client in android. For example, lets say i want to keep the users by their phone number like whatssap. How can I send the number to the server beforehand i send the message? 
  If i could do that I would try to get the phone number and the message in a multimap and serve to the client afterwards but i couldn't figure out how to do it. So far i tried this code but it didn't work. The problem with this code is that when i add the clients in the for(;;) loop it just don't broadcast the message to this specific client. But if i do that in the upside and out of for loop it sends the message to the client. how can i resolve it?Any suggestions?

```
public class ChatServer {


private static final String USAGE = "Usage: java ChatServer";
String gonderen1;
String alan1;
/** Default port number on which this server to be run. */
private static final int PORT_NUMBER = 8000;
Map<String, List<PrintWriter>> clients;
List<PrintWriter> clientwriter;
ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();

public ChatServer() {
    clients = new HashMap<String, List<PrintWriter>>();
    clientwriter = new LinkedList<PrintWriter>();

}

/** Starts the server. */
public void start() {

    try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER); 
        for (;;) {
            Socket incoming = s.accept(); 
            new ClientHandler(incoming).start(); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("AndyChat server stopped."); 
}

/** Adds a new client identified by the given print writer. */
private void addClient(PrintWriter out,String alan) {
    synchronized(clientwriter) {

        clientwriter.add(out);
       clients.put(alan, clientwriter);

    }
}

/** Adds the client with given print writer. */
private void removeClient(PrintWriter out) {
    synchronized(clientwriter) {

        clientwriter.remove(out);
        clients.remove(alan1);

    }
}

/** Broadcasts the given text to all clients. */
private void broadcast(String msg,String alan) {

    for(PrintWriter out : clients.get(alan)){

        out.println(msg);
        out.flush();

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        System.out.println(USAGE);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    new ChatServer().start();
}

/** A thread to serve a client. This class receive messages from a
 * client and broadcasts them to all clients including the message
 * sender. */
private class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket incoming; 

    public ClientHandler(Socket incoming) {
        this.incoming = incoming;
    }

    /** Starts receiving and broadcasting messages. */
    public void run() {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(incoming.getOutputStream()));

            // inform the server of this new client           
          /* ChatServer.this.addClient(out,"mert");

            out.print("Welcome to AndyChat! mert");
            out.println("Enter BYE to exit."); 
            out.flush();*/

            BufferedReader in 
                = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream())); 
            String msg;
            for(;;)  {
             msg = in.readLine();
            if(msg!=null){
             liste.add(msg);
                    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<Gonderen>(.*?)</Gonderen>");
                    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(msg);
                    if (mat.find()) {
                        gonderen1 = mat.group(1).replaceAll("\\s",""); // => "3"
                        System.out.println("Gonderen "+gonderen1);
                    }
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Alan>(.*?)</Alan>");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);

                    if (m.find()) {
                        alan1 = m.group(1).replaceAll("\\s",""); // => "3"          
                        out.print("dsa");
                         System.out.println("Alanin adi "+alan1);
                    }
                    if(alan1!=null){
                        System.out.println(clients.get("mert"));
                    ChatServer.this.addClient(out,alan1);}}

                    ChatServer.this.broadcast(msg,"mert");
                    System.out.println("null gelmedi");}
                    if(msg==null){break;}

                }



            incoming.close(); 
            ChatServer.this.removeClient(out);
             } catch (Exception e) {

            if (out != null) {
                ChatServer.this.removeClient(out);
            }
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `How can I send the number to the server beforehand i send the message?` What is the problem? You first send the phone number then the message.

Comment: if i send them together when i read it in the buffered reader on the server, when it enters the infinite loop if i add the client in the loop it won't broadcast the message if i add in the outside it sends the message but i can not get the phone number @greenapps

Comment: I do not understand anything what you are saying. If you say `How can I send the number to the server beforehand...` then i suppose that that you are talking about your client. `if i send them together` .You are again speaking about your client?

Comment: if you look at the code after reading my comment i think you will understand what my problem is what i mean is if i add the client as soon as the connection establishes i can not get the phone number but broadcast the data if i add the client with the phone number i can not broadcast the data

Comment: I did not look your code. And i will not until you have given a better description of what is actually happening. Please adapt your intro text. As long as there is `How can I send the number to the server beforehand` your intro is unreadable as everybody will think that that is a client problem.